# Ignore formulas while Pasting values while copying from data table to multiple sheets?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to transfer data from a database into multiple sheets in a workbook having the same template. However, I wan't to ignore the formulas while copying. My current macro gives error of circular referencing while transferring the data.

How can I ignore the formula while copy data to different templates through a looping process.

Also I would like to know how can I transfer data from multiple/different columns referenced from `wkSht.Name` to different columns of the template sheets.

The following code only transfers data from `Range(cell.Offset(0, 18), cell.Offset(18, 18)` of the master sheet to `O17` cell of the template sheets of the same workbook.

Can anyone update the code and add criteria for copying cell values only instead of formula.

```
Sub FC()
Dim wkSht As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Sheets("Combine").Range("A4:A600").Cells

    For Each wkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    
        If cell.Value = wkSht.Name Then
       
        Sheets("Combine").Range(cell.Offset(0, 18), cell.Offset(18, 18)).Copy wkSht.Range("O17")
        
        End If
    
    Next wkSht

Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Do you need copying the format, too? Is there only one occurrence of the sheet name in A:A column of `Sheets("Combine")`?

Comment: Copying the format is not essential

Comment: OK. I will place an answer in some minutes...

Comment: Please, test the code I pasted. If necessary, I will comment it. Not time now to do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, test the next code:

```
Sub FC()
 Dim wkSht As Worksheet, wsC As Worksheet, rngSearch As Range
 Dim shNCell As Range

Set wsC = Sheets("Combine")
Set rngSearch = wsC.Range("A4:A600")
    For Each wkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        'find the sheet name cell in rngSearch:
        Set shNCell = rngSearch.Find(what:=wkSht.Name, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
        'if found:
        If Not shNCell Is Nothing Then
          'copy the below built array in the necessary place
          wkSht.Range("O17").Resize(19, 1).value = wsC.Range(shNCell.Offset(0, 18), shNCell.Offset(18, 18)).value
        End If
    Next wkSht
End Sub
```

Not tested, but this should be the idea. If something goes wrong, please tell me what the problem it does (or does not...).

I will comment the code lines in some minutes, after finishing something urgent...

Comment: @Samiul Didn't you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it work as you need? If not, what problem does it have?